# One tenured job to another tenured one?

Tags: united-states, career-path, job-search, tenure-track, associate-professor

I have recently been promoted to associate professor with tenure. But I want to relocate to another institution of similar rating. Is it possible to get an offer **with tenure** from another institution in the US? How common/uncommon is it in the US? Advices on the procedure with respect to the US academia will be highly appreciated.

The central part of my question is about the possibility for retaining the **'tenured'** status at the mid-career move (e.g., how common it is and how to negotiate).

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/824/13240

Comment: Thank you @AnonymousPhysicist for pointing to the earlier posts. Those are insightful, but do not address my question. The central part of my question is about the possibility for retaining 'tenured' status.

Comment: Usually one does not move unless one retains the same rank or gets a higher rank.  So yes, tenured status is usually retained.

Comment: As discussed in the other question, there is not a standard procedure.

Comment: Thank you @AnonymousPhysicist !

Answer (score 7):

It is possible.  It is done all the time.  But you should not expect getting any tenured or tenure-track job to be easy.  Advice:  Don't resign your current job until you get the new one.

**added**
My experience:
Perhaps the usual would be hiring an associate professor with a one-year probationary period, after which tenure would be determined.  Our university was reluctant to grant tenure immediately, so if we wanted it our chairman would have to make a special plea to the dean or even the provost.  On the other hand, I never saw the tenure denied after the one-year period.

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar for responding to the central part of my question (which is about the possibility for retaining 'tenured' status). I surely won't quit job before securing another offer :). Any advice on the key factors in the negotiation for retaining tenured status?

Comment: @relocator They should really want to hire you, and you should make it clear that you won't come without tenure. (Of course, if you are desperate to leave for whatever reason, this might be difficult.)

Comment: I would think that a two year probationary period is also pretty common, especially for someone at the beginning of their career. I think that tenure-at-hire is pretty uncommon except for senior level superstars.

Comment: @Buffy - although I’ve known a few senior level superstars who didn’t care about tenure at all.

Comment: Let me add that I've seen people taking a sabbatical in one university and use that for that "one-year probation period", and then they can decide if they move or not.